# Odd/even using subtraction or addition operation

Tags: java

Anybody know how to identify a given number is odd/even using addition or subtraction operator? I am new to coding and don't have an idea how to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Isn't using the remainder operator a better solution?

Comment: @Tanay homework on loops?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a math question, not specifically about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using addition

```
int inputNumber = 12;
int absInputNumber = Math.abs(inputNumber)
int i = 0;
while(i < absInputNumber) {
    i += 2
}
if(inputNumber==i)
    System.out.println("Even Number");
else
    System.out.println("Odd Number");
```

Comment: you can do it without using any math library function as well. Absolute function will be required there where you will store the user input number in float or double. As here you are using integer data type so if user enters a number with decimal places , the decimal places will be discarded by integer data type because it will only save the number without decimal places.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone is advocating using this method

Answer (score 7):

using subtraction.

```
int inputNumber = 12;

    while(inputNumber>2)
    {
        inputNumber-=2;
    }
    if(inputNumber==1)
        System.out.println("Odd Number");
    else
        System.out.println("Even Number");
```

Comment: This works for positive numbers only.

Comment: For -ve number just need to add a check whether the number is negative, change the while condition like inputNumber<-2 and inside the while loop inputNumber+=2; and the if condition will be like inputNumber==-1 for odd.

Comment: @robin, it's easier to just create a positive `int absInput = Math.abs(inputNumber)` and then use that. `|a|` is even iff `a` is even.

Comment: @Trengot true agreed .

Answer (score 0):

Java answer (without reference to Math class):

```
package odd.even.tester;

public class OddEvenTester {
    public boolean isEven(int number) {
        int evaluatedValue = number;
        if (evaluatedValue < 0) {
            evaluatedValue *= (-1);
        }
        while (evaluatedValue > 0) {
            evaluatedValue -= 2;
        }
        return evaluatedValue == 0;
    }
}
```

short test:

```
package odd.even.tester;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;

public class OddEvenTesterTest {
    @Test
    public void testIsEven() {
        OddEvenTester tester = new OddEvenTester();
        assertTrue(tester.isEven(-10));
        assertTrue(tester.isEven(-8));
        assertTrue(tester.isEven(-6));
        assertTrue(tester.isEven(-4));
        assertTrue(tester.isEven(-2));
        assertTrue(tester.isEven(0));
        assertTrue(tester.isEven(2));
        assertTrue(tester.isEven(4));
        assertTrue(tester.isEven(6));
        assertTrue(tester.isEven(8));
        assertTrue(tester.isEven(10));

        assertFalse(tester.isEven(-9));
        assertFalse(tester.isEven(-7));
        assertFalse(tester.isEven(-5));
        assertFalse(tester.isEven(-3));
        assertFalse(tester.isEven(-1));
        assertFalse(tester.isEven(1));
        assertFalse(tester.isEven(3));
        assertFalse(tester.isEven(5));
        assertFalse(tester.isEven(7));
        assertFalse(tester.isEven(9));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do it using "mod" which is the '%' symbol.  If you have a number and use % 2, then if the answer is 0 it is even, if it is 1 it is odd.

Example:

```
int test = 12
if (test % 2 == 0) 
    System.out.print("Even.");
else
    System.out.print("Odd.");
```

You can incorporate this in the addition and subtraction operators.

Comment: He asked for a solution that used either addition or subtraction. Modulo operation is not the case here :)